# Specify pandas histogram x and y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | England | Red | 10 |
| Oranges | Scotland | Orange | 20 |
| Pears | Wales | Green | 30 |

I am trying to plot four histograms to view their distribution

1. The sum of count for all unique values in Col_A
2. The sum of count for all unique values in Col_B
3. The sum of count for all unique values in Col_C
4. The sum of count for all combinations of values in Col_A + Col_B + Col_C

Here is an example of what one would look like

[image]

I have tried

```
df2.hist(column=['Col_A', 'Col_A', 'Col_C', 'Count'])
```

But this just gives a histogram of each separate instance of a Count.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called bar plots, not histograms.

You need to group by unique values in one of the first three columns and sum the corresponding counts in the last column, e.g.:

```
df.groupby('Col_A').sum().plot.bar()
```

For the last plot, group by all columns:

```
df.groupby(['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C']).sum().plot.bar()
```